# Difference between two dates from user input moment js

Tags: javascript

This is my form:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Check in date" id="checkin" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Check out date" id="checkout" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="result()" id="submit" />
</form>
```

And this is my javascript for calculating the money=days*price

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function result()
    {   
          var a = document.getElementById("checkin").value;
          var b = document.getElementById("checkout").value;

          var checkin = moment(a).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
          var checkout = moment(b).format('DD-MM-YYYY');        

          var days= checkout.diff(checkin, 'days');

          var price=100;
          alert("The money you have to pay is: "+days*price);


    }
</script>
```

This is my test case: 
checkin date = 05-12-2014,
checkout date = 25-12-2014
When I click submit, nothing happens.
Can anyone please explain to me why and how can I fix this. Thank you!

Comment: What is not working and please provide a code snippet or a working fiddle.

Comment: Keep your crome console open to see what is error.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function result(e) //e refers to event.
{   
      e.preventDefault();
      var a = document.getElementById("checkin").value;
      var b = document.getElementById("checkout").value;

      var checkin = moment(a, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
      var checkout = moment(b, 'DD-MM-YYYY');        

      var days= checkout.diff(checkin, 'days');

      var price=100;
      alert("The money you have to pay is: "+days*price);


}
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Check in date" id="checkin" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Check out date" id="checkout" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="result(event)" id="submit" />
</form>
```

First of all you're submitting the form. You need to prevent that using `event.preventDefault()`. I think your problems will melt away after that. I strongly suggest to restrict the date inputs. Either use a library to select dates from a picker or provide the user with some guidance to the date format.

Comment: Thank you sir, but your answer doesn't work, I'm using Moment.js and I think the problem is: the format of the user input is not valid for the diff function to work.

Comment: @lightnguyen the updated answer works. When I input `15-02-2015` and `18-02-2015` the price is `300`, which is three days, which is correct.

Comment: Your original answer wouldn't have worked. It was actually wrong moment date creation which you corrected after copying from answer below...

Comment: @kushdilip, Not quite, The first and main problem was the submitting of the form. Secondly the `diff` function wasn't working what I already found out. I was looking into `moment.js` and was updating my question with the complete and correct code.

Comment: cool. checkout this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kakuko/2/edit?html,js,output) .
It works just by momentjs changes..

Answer (score 1):

Use this to convert dates to moment dates

```
  var checkin = moment(a, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
  var checkout = moment(b, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

See the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kakuko/2/edit?html,js)

Comment: It still submits the data, there is no action on the form. I think it isn't necessary.